# Не компилируется код с лямбдой - expression having type 'const std::mt19937' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

есть такой код (упрощённый):

```
void make() 
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(this->min, this->max);

    const auto graphFunc = [this, generator, distribution](double x) -> double
    {
        return distribution(generator);
    };

    // ... use graphFunc
}
```

выдающий следующую ошибку компиляции:

> Error  C3848   expression having type 'const std::mt19937' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'unsigned int std::mersenne_twister<_Ty,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18>::operator ()(void)'   \microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\random 316

У объекта `rd` конструктор копирования и присваивания объявлены как удалённые, судя по коду из `random.h`

`random_device(const random_device&) = delete;
 random_device& operator=(const random_device&) = delete;`

Имеет ли это отношение к коду выше ? - на мой взгляд имеет так как `generator` копируясь в лямбду должен ещё вызвать конструктор копирования объекта `rd` который удалён

какие тогда есть обходные варианты ?

И в чём суть этой ошибки компиляции ?

Comment: Уберите квалификатор const у лямбда выражения.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а почему `const` может помешать ? я убрал - та же ошибка возникает

Comment: может ещё добавить что компилятором от `visual studio 2015`

Comment: @ampawd потому что generator - изменяемая переменная!

Comment: Вы не можете получить случайное число не изменив состояние ГСЧ (иначе ГСЧ выдавал бы одно и то же число каждый раз)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не там смотрите. Для передачи в распределение вам нужен изменяемый объект generator - но он у вас захвачен по значению в неизменяемой лямбде.

Вы не можете получить случайное число не изменив состояние ГСЧ - иначе ГСЧ выдавал бы каждый раз одно и то же число.

Если раскрыть вашу лямбду - получится примерно вот это:

```
class GraphFunc {
  std::mt19937 generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
public:
  GraphFunc(std::mt19937 generator, std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution) 
    : generator(generator), distribution(distribution) {}

  double operator() (double x) const {
    return distribution(generator);
  }
} const graphFunc(generator, distribution);
```

Тут есть три проблемы:

1. `operator()` объявлен как константный (не меняющий состояние объекта) - что мешает передать ссылку на generator в distribution. Добавьте `mutable` к определению лямбды, чтобы `operator()` перестал быть константным.
2. переменная `graphFunc` объявлена как константная - что не дает вызывать неконстантные методы. Уберите `const`.
3. При захвате `generator` копируется - что может привести к паразитным корреляциям между разными последовательностями, если вы будете его использовать где-то еще. Надо захватывать его по ссылке.

   Пример паразитной корреляции: https://ideone.com/boR272

   Пример решения проблемы: https://ideone.com/lLnyfL

   Если время жизни лямбды больше времени жизни локальной переменной - используйте std::shared_ptr вместо ссылки.

Comment: а обязательно добавлять `mutable` без него компилируется прекрасно - или это для наглядности ?

Comment: @ampawd это особенность `cl` (компилятора студии) - он иногда игнорирует константность. Но, вообще говоря, это некорректное поведение, которое делает ваш код непереносимым.

Comment: @ampawd те же `gcc` и `clang` без `mutable` код не скомпилируют - а добавить-то его не сложно.

Comment: даже не убрав `const` у перемнной `graphFunc` всё равно компилируется

Comment: @ampawd сейчас вы придете к тому, что у вас и исходный код тоже компилировался :)

Comment: не, тот вариант кода который в вопросе - не компилируется никак ) но стоит по ссылке передать `generator` как всё норм - и ваши замечания по поводу ГСЧ имеют смысл

Comment: @ampawd как я уже говорил, это особенность `cl` - точнее, того как он работает со ссылками.

Comment: _"Пример решения проблемы: [https://ideone.com/lLnyfL](https://ideone.com/lLnyfL)"_ не компилируется...

Comment: @Qwertiy экспериментировал с ним и нажал "редактировать" вместо "fork". Спасибо, что заметили.